# Is there any standard of notation for ecological diagrams?

Tags: ecology

#### General Question

Is there any convention of how to express different types of relations (e.g., *eats, turns into, is beneficial to*) and agents (e.g., *species, nutrient)* in an ecological diagram? I know that inhibitory relationships are indicated by barred arrows, but I failed to find anything going beyond this.

#### Example

Suppose, I want to express that Species A excretes Nutrient X, which in turn is metabolised by Species B. Naïvely, I would sketch this as follows:

[image: example diagram]

However, this it not necessarily clear:

- I here arbitrarily used squares and circles to distinguish species and nutrients.
  If you do not know this, you could not immediately distinguish them.
  (Of course, I may just use specific examples like *tree* instead of *A,* but then for my theoretical cases, a tree is too concrete.)
- The arrows mean different things.
  The left arrow means *excretes,* the right arrow means *is metabolised by.*
  Moreover, the arrows could be mistaken for something like *turns into* or a general *is beneficial to.*

How would I denote the above relation unambiguously in a diagram?